# Mysql Database Design/Choice

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-design

Scenario:

I have the task to add a new field on a form, which is called account number. When a user clicks submit, it goes and submit the appropriate data to the appropriate tables...not important.

Currently, the tables that are involved are 3: customers, orders, and accounts.

The tables structures are:

- Customers -> customer_id (PK), ...
- Orders -> order_id (PK), customer_id (FK), ...
- Accounts -> order_id (PK), account_number, ...

As you can see, a customer can have many orders, and each orders can have only one account.

Even though in the table structure I added PK and FK, the database engine is actually MyISAM, which doesn't support transactions and relationships. To add "relationship" between tables, the previous developer(s) decided to add the appropriate PK and FK to "fake" the relationships between tables.

**PLEASE NOTE:** I did not have any part of creating the database and tables; it was given to me as is.

**The business logic is that a customer can have only one account.**

As far as I know, the way the tables are mapped out, a customer has more than one account.

Without redesigning the tables, it looks like that I don't have a choice.

This is what I have in mind without redesigning the tables:

- Create a SQL script to clean up and update account numbers in accounts, so that each account will have the same account number for a particular customer...even though a customer has many oders.
- Anywhere in the web app that can insert an account number, I have to check to see if the customer has an account number. If so, then come back with a message stating that the customer already has an account number...maybe select the account number or update it with a new one. If not, then insert it.

Any better options?

By the way, I'm using MySQL and PHP/CodeIgniter.

Comment: Use innoDB to use foreign key constraints

Comment: I can't. With the current design, how can I have one customer for one account?

Comment: Going forward, don't allow creation of new account numbers if one already exists and provide one automatically if there is (I would choose the most recent one in the DB, ordered by descending ID or date created).

For however account numbers are used, present only the most recent account number to the user, and when pulling data from DB, include ALL account numbers that exist for the customer ID

Comment: @TrungNguyen thanks. I will try your suggestion as I think this is the only way.